# How to convert from char (ASCII character) to scientific notation saving in a string variable in C

Tags: c, string, ascii

**Hello Colleagues,**

I have a question about my code copied below. I use some functions from some users of StackOverflow in order to complete my piece of code (I don't know if I need to mention the source of code), but I'm seeing that convert several times the same variable is very inefficient.

**I obtain a variable from a file in ASCII format (4 bytes):**

```
  42F00000 in hex (in ASCII you will see unprintable characters)
```

**Code:**

```
  //This code works in the main:
  //
  //I take out four bytes in ASCII format (from 0 to F representing
  //hex characters) from a file and save them in the "temp4" variable.

    arrayhexrcv[] comes from a file.

    unsigned char temp4[3] = "";
    unsigned long int tempul = 0ul;
    float tempf = 0.0f;
    char speed[12] = "";

    temp4[0] = arrayhexrcv[0];
    temp4[1] = arrayhexrcv[1];
    temp4[2] = arrayhexrcv[2];
    temp4[3] = arrayhexrcv[3];

  //The first conversion is from ASCII to hex to obtain an hex string.
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        snprintf(temp4doble+(i*2), 9, "%02X", temp4[i]);
  //2nd conversion is from hex to Unsigned Long Int.
    tempul = strtoul(temp4doble, NULL, 16);
  //3rd conversion is from Unsigned Long Int to Float.
    tempf = UliAFloat(tempul);
  //4th conversion is from Float to a string with the characters with 
  //value in scientific format.
    snprintf(speed, 13, "%e", tempf);
    printf("Speed in string of float is: %s\n, speed);

  //UliAFloat function: This function converts Unsigned Long Int in Float.
    #include<stdio.h>
    float UliAFloat(unsigned long int x) {
    union {
        unsigned long int x;
        float f;
    } temp;
    temp.x = x;
    return temp.f;
    }
```

**At the end of the day I obtained the following value in a string representing a scientific format:**

```
1.200000e+02 (Speed in string format)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Note: Taking the question at face value, it is a request for a code review. As such, it _might_ fit better over at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (but read their guidance first). However, there is a lot of confusion in the question so that can be addressed here.

Comment: Review `unsigned char temp4[3] = ""; ... temp4[3] = arrayhexrcv[3];`. Code is accessing outside array bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At the end of the day, and based on that Tom and Chux answered, the complete answer would be:**

```
  //Speed.
   temp4[3] = arrayhexrcv[3];
   temp4[2] = arrayhexrcv[2];
   temp4[1] = arrayhexrcv[1];
   temp4[0] = arrayhexrcv[0];
   sprintf(timestamp, "%e", *(float *)temp4);
   printf("Timestamp: %s\n", timestamp);
```

The most important issue is that you can change the end type of string doing the following.

If you need to save in a string variable a float:

```
   sprintf(speed, "%e", *(float *)temp4);
```

If you need to save in a string variable a unsigned long int:

```
   sprintf(speed, "%lu", *(unsigned long int *)temp4);
```

At the end of the program I'll use the string variables to make a JSON file.

Another option would be usign snprintf():

```
    snprintf(speed, 11, "%lu", *(unsigned long int *)temp4);
```

Number "11" includes end character '\0'.

**Thanks so much for your help.**

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rewrite this because it is inefficient; I would rewrite because it is too complicated.

Also, today you seem confused between ASCII, hexadecimal and bytes. Bytes, in a file or memory, are serialized data. A value sometimes takes one byte, sometimes more; sometimes a fixed number, sometimes a variable number. (Very occasionally, a value takes less than a byte.) When a value takes more than one byte, byte order (aka endianness) matters. (ASCII is a character encoding for text, which doesn't have much to do with anything here.)

Hexadecimal is a sometimes convenient way of *discussing* the value of a byte or group of bytes. Where one must use text, one way to represent arbitrary byte values is to convert the bytes to hexadecimal.

You seem to have serialized `float` (IEEE-754 single-precision, floating-point number) value in a file. It's 32 bits. Ideally, the way to read that would be with `fread`). But, you have it in an array (presumably of `char`).

We're into a lot implementation-defined behavior here. Assume [CHAR_BITS](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Width-of-Type.html) == 8.) So, 32 bits takes 4 bytes. Also, assume that the float is serialized in little endian order, in this example with an initialized array, or at least in the same order as is native in your machine with the bytes being read from a file.

```
char arrayhexrcv[4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x42}; // little endian to match my machine
```

You simply need to take the address of the float and access it as a float:

```
printf("%e\n", *(float *)arrayhexrcv);
```

Comment: `*(float *)arrayhexrcv` can readily fail due to misalignment.  Consider `union` or `memcpy()`.

Comment: @chux Yes, this is highly implementation dependent. `union` might also present misalignment issues but the implementation might offer explicit control over alignment.

Comment: Thanks for you comments Tom and Chux. The issue is that the files comes with the data in characters indicating hex values. Next step is to convert these variables (544 in total) in a JSON file;  for this reason I need to convert all values (float, integers, chars, etc.) In a great string to make the JSON.